# only show values from selected option

Tags: javascript, php, html

I’m trying to understand how to work with PHP and tables. When we have is the following database:

[image: tblBestemmingen]

Right now I’m showing all the information inside my webpage like so:

[image: Webpage]

But when I would like now, when you select any kind of option (land) from the option tag I would like that the table ONLY shows the value from that land. But I have no idea how to do so..

here is my code so far:

HTML:

```html
<?php
require_once('scripts/config.php');
require_once('scripts/api.php');
session_start();
$bestemmingen = CallAPI("GET", $DB . "/tblbestemming/");
$vluchten = CallAPI("GET", $DB . "/tblvlucht");

$landen = array();
foreach ($bestemmingen as $bestemming) {
    $landen[] = $bestemming['Land'];
}
$landen = array_filter(array_map('trim', $landen));
$land_uniek = array_unique($landen);
sort($land_uniek);
?>

<?php require_once('views/shared/_header.inc'); ?>
    <body>
<header>
    <?php include('views/shared/_nav.inc'); ?>
</header>
<main>
    <div id="load"></div>
    <div id="contents">
        <section class="container">
            <label for="bestemmingen">Bestemming</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="bestemmingen">
                <option>Show all</option>
                <?php
                foreach ($land_uniek as $l_u => $key) {
                    echo "<option value='$l_u' name='bestemmingen'>$key</option>";
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover sortable">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Bestemming</th>
                    <th>Land</th>
                    <th>Type vlucht</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                foreach ($bestemmingen as $bestemming) {
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>' . $bestemming['Voluit'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $bestemming['Land'] . '</td>';
                    if ($bestemming['TypeVlucht'] == 1) {
                        echo '<td> Korte vlucht </td>';
                    } else {
                        echo '<td> Lange vlucht </td>';
                    }
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
                ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </thead>
            </table>
        </section>
    </div>
</main>
<?php require_once('views/shared/_footer.inc'); ?>
```

Comment: You got several options. Either you simply tag the table rows (ex: `<tr data-tag="someoption">`) with the option value and hide all that doesn't match using JS, you could also reload the page, passing the option in the querystring and just fetch the matching rows from the database (using WHERE) or you can use ajax  where you're passing the option to a php-file thats fetching the matching rows and then you repopulate the table with that data using JS.

Comment: Keep in mind that when implementing the requested functionality in PHP it means that for each filter selection a page reload is required. You need a post action to reload the page with the filter (selected country) as a parameter and then retrieve the corresponding data. It might be worth looking at a javascript plugin like https://datatables.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the table an ID

Add `data-land="'$countryname.'"` to all TRs

```
foreach ($bestemmingen as $bestemming) {
  echo '<tr data-land="'. $bestemming['Land'] .'">'
```

then select all rows and test if they contain the country from the select

like this:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector("#bestemmingen").onchange = function() {
    var land = this.value;
    var countryRows = document.querySelectorAll("#countryTable>tbody>tr");
    for (var i = 0; i < countryRows.length; i++) {
      var row = countryRows[i],
        show = land == "" || row.getAttribute("data-land") == land;
      countryRows[i].style.display = show ? "" : "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="contents">
  <section class="container">
    <label for="bestemmingen">Bestemming</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="bestemmingen">
                <option value="">Show all</option>
                <option value="Nederland">Nederland</option>
                <option value="Denemarken">Denemarken</option>
            </select>
    <table id="countryTable" class="table table-striped table-hover sortable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Bestemming</th>
          <th>Land</th>
          <th>Type vlucht</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr data-land="Denemarken">
          <td>DK CPH Kastrup</td>
          <td>Denemarken</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-land="Nederland">
          <td>NL AMS Schiphol</td>
          <td>Nederland</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-land="Denemarken">
          <td>DK BLL Billund</td>
          <td>Denemarken</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-land="Nederland">
          <td>NL RTM Rotterdam</td>
          <td>Nederland</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: It's probably better to use the `data`-attribute than the `class`-attribute (since if you're unlucky, the class attribute might actually change the presentation if it contains a valid class name).

Comment: You're still adding the class attribute, though. If you removed that, you could still just do: `var rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr');`. It might be me that's picky, I just don't like having classes that have other meanings than styling. :-)

Comment: Well, if we slap an ID on the table, I think that would be fine, actually.

Comment: You could do `theid > tbody> tr`? If that's possible with the query selector, that is. On the other hand, it kind of looks like the OP is using bootstrap or something, which makes me believe that jQuery is included. But I like vanilla JS-answers better, anyway :-) More flexible for future visitors.

Comment: Okeeeeeeeeeeeee... jävla... ;)

Comment: could you please explain this part of je JS: 

countries[i].style.display=countries[i].getAttribute("data-land")==land)?"":"none";

it seems to be giving me an error, and i don't understand it.

Comment: `"’.$countryname.’"` should be `"'.$countryname.'"` (wrong quotes)

Comment: Mobile keyboard changed in iOS 11

Comment: @Ramon which error? It is a ternary operator. Perhaps your table is rewritten using some sorting plugin?

Comment: on the line from the JS i dont understand i got this error inside my console:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Comment: Ah. That is likely a typo or paste error. I would need to create a working version or see your code with my changes. It is only a snippet of code. It needs to live in an onload handler

Comment: Change `==land)?` to `==land?`

Comment: thanks, as of now i have the following error: 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onchange' of null

and whenever i change the option my table is just gone.

Comment: I’ll create a working example in an hour or so. If you use a lot of plugins it may be hard to insert in your page

Comment: Please see update. I would need to see the code you have when you "inspect" the table, if my code does not work for you

Comment: Thanks allot, its working now. I do have one more little problem. Some of the countries are listed in the database as follow “Nederland” but some are “Nederland “ with one space at the end. Thad’s why I included an array_filter. But now when I select “Nederland” from the list, the ones that are inside the database with a space at the and are not showing.

Comment: Then trim them before inserting them anywhere: `. trim($bestemming[“Land”]) .`